# How do I get data from 2 buttons to differentiate which button was pressed and execute the correct code in jquery/html?

Tags: jquery, laravel

The code apparently cannot distinguish which button was clicked. I was hoping that depending which button was clicked it sets 1 or 0 to the hidden field and then executes the correct code. What is wrong here, can you please help me in finding out?

```
{!! Form::hidden('hidden_autoCalculate', '0', ['id' => 'hidden_autoCalculate']) !!}
<data id="dialog_time_record_update_id_autoCalc" data-autoCalculate='1' class="btn midium time_record_update">
  {{trans('time_record/time_record_day.calculate')}}
</data>
<data id="{{$dialog_time_record_update_id}}" data-autoCalculate='0' class="btn midium time_record_update">
  {{trans('time_record/time_record_day.noCalculate')}}
</data>
```

```
$('.time_record_update').click(function() {
    $('#hidden_autoCalculate').val($(this).data('autoCalculate'));
});
```

Comment: $(this).attr('data-autoCalculate')); try this It works sort of here https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vqQQOW

Comment: Thanks! I figured out the problem. Apparently when using data- with camelCase you have to put hyphen so I just edited it to data-auto-calculate and it worked. Didn't know it's a HTML thing. Newbie here.

Comment: good luck on the rest of it

Answer (score 0):

You can check for the data-attribute:

```
$('.time_record_update').click(function() {
    if($(this).attr('data-auto-calculate')) == 1){
      //first clicked
    } else {
      //second clicked
    }
    $('#hidden_autoCalculate').val($(this).data('auto-calculate'));
});
```